# how to disable wordpress logo and search bar at top?

Tags: wordpress

How to remove Wordpress logo at top left side and search bar at top right side?

Like here:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please ask more specific!

Comment: I think those items show up when you are logged in. Are they there when you are logged out? To edit in Wordpress, you would need to edit template files to make changes of this kind. There are plenty of resources online for this to get you started.

Comment: I pulled in your screen shot, but please understand that this community isn't service where you drop requirements and other people drop code. Things work much better when you *try* to solve your problem yourself, to then ask specific questions when something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You have to edit your theme's template files, probably the `header.php` and remove the corresponding code there. However, as soon as the theme gets updated, it will be back again, so you'd have to create a child theme whose files won't get overwritten when the theme is updated (search for that on wordpress.org)

Answer (score 0):

The admin bar only appears if you are logged in.

To remove it, you need to uncheck "Show Toolbar when viewing site":

[image]

You could also use `show_admin_bar(false);` in your **functions.php**.